# SQL Server : Improving query performance?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008

I am comparatively new to SQL Server queries.

I am trying to write a query where the branches of my companies are displayed. I have 3 ways to do so :

1. Write a subquery:

   ```
   Select
       (Select branchname 
           from branchtable 
           where branchPK = primarycompanybranchfk
       ) as branchone,
       (Select branchname 
           from branchtable 
           where branchPK = secondarycompanybranchfk
       ) as branchtwo
   from companytable
   ```
2. Using joins:

   ```
   Select 
       a.branchname as branchone,
       b.branchname as branchtwo
   from companytable c
   left join branchtable a     
       on a.branchPK = c.primarycompanybranchfk
   left join branchtable b 
       on b.branchPK = c.secondarycompanybranchfk
   ```
3. Using joins of subtables:

   ```
    Select 
       branchfirst.branchname as branchone,
       branchsecond.branchname as branchtwo
    from companytable c
    left join (
       Select branchPK as prikey,
            branchname as branchname 
       from branchtable
    ) branchfirst 
           on branchfirst.prikey= c.primarycompanybranchfk
   left join (
       Select branchPK as prikey,
           branchname as branchname 
       from branchtable
   ) branchsecond 
       on branchsecond.prikey= c.secondarycompanybranchfk
   ```

Is there any performance improvement if I use the 3rd scenario over the 2nd or vice versa if my branch table contains more than 10 columns?

Comment: SQL Server, as well as several other Microsoft products, tends to have two different numbers associated with each release -  one is a "marketing" version number, which in recent years has been the year number, and the other is the internal version number (which is displayed in a number of places). You shouldn't shorten a year version number because the two numbers don't line up (often). E.g. SQL Server version 8 was marketed as "SQL Server 2000", whereas "SQL Server 2008" has a version number of 10.

Comment: And - btw - one more info: @Damien_The_Unbeliever will not get a notification without using the `@` sign together with his username. So he might not even get your thanks...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : Thanks for the info on version numbers.

Comment: @Shnugo: Noted sir! Thank you

Comment: Hi @Shnugo, I do accept the answers which solves the issue which I am facing.

Answer (score 0):

And one more hint :-)  Try to set up a sample everybody can reproduce. Using your own tables makes this more difficult...

In most cases 2 and 3 will be quite the same, the "nested column" is in this case the fastest:

Try this and set the "include execution plan" option. So you can compare the execution plans afterwards (There are two more variants with `CROSS APPLY` which are quite the same as 2 and 3).

What happens exactly is - of course - much more complex with a more complex scenario. It depends on existing indexes and statistics.

```
SELECT c.COLUMN_NAME,
    (SELECT t.TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t WHERE c.TABLE_NAME=t.TABLE_NAME) AS TABLE_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS as c

SELECT c.COLUMN_NAME,t.TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS as c
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t ON c.TABLE_NAME=t.TABLE_NAME

SELECT c.COLUMN_NAME,t.TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS as c
INNER JOIN (SELECT t.TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t) AS t ON c.TABLE_NAME=t.TABLE_NAME

SELECT c.COLUMN_NAME,t.TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS as c
CROSS APPLY INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t 
WHERE c.TABLE_NAME=t.TABLE_NAME

SELECT c.COLUMN_NAME,t.TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS as c
CROSS APPLY (SELECT t.TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t WHERE c.TABLE_NAME=t.TABLE_NAME) AS t
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case both will have same performance as the query optimizer will treat both as same query. however if you have a filter in nested query, then it will act faster.

Its good to join with the required amount of data and not on complete dataset.